# Getting a linker symbol for a constexpr global variable (not a static member)

Tags: c++, c++11

I can write the following for a static member:

```
// foo.h
struct A {
    static constexpr int x = 2;
};
// foo.cpp
constexpr int A::x;
```

Is it possible to do the same for a top-level variable?  This doesn't work in C++11:

```
// foo.h
constexpr int x = 2;
// foo.cpp
constexpr int x;
```

It fails with:

```
<source>:3:15: error: redefinition of 'constexpr const int x'
```

Adding static to the expressions doesn't help either. I know a workaround is to just make it a static member, but I'd like to understand why the non-member version doesn't work.

Comment: The first example works because in the structure you only *declare* the variable `x`, and then in the source file you *define* it. In the second example toy have a definition in each source file where you include the header file, plus one in the `foo.cpp` source file. Having two or more definitions is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This was a PEBKAC. You can take addresses of constexpr variables:

```
constexpr int x = 2;
const int* const f() {
    return &x;
}
```

This works correctly: a linker section for `x` gets generated, and it doesn't matter how many times this declaration is repeated. So there isn't really any good reason to *want* to do the same idiom that is necessary for static constexpr members.

Comment: This idiom is also no longer necessary for static constexpr members and is in fact depricated, as of C++17.

Comment: Note the behavior of this example is different between C++14 and C++17! In C++14, a namespace scope `constexpr` variable has internal linkage, so the address of `x` will be different from different translation units. In C++17, `constexpr` on a variable implies `inline` (and "inline variables" are a new thing in C++17), the variable has external linkage, and it will always have the same address.